# What's the difference between "take in" / "bring in" / "pull in" moneywise?

Tags: meaning, phrases, synonyms

For the most part, it seems these words can be used interchangeably in most situations.

Salary - He took in $5,000 last month / She brought in $100,000 last year / I pulled in a lot of money.

Sales - The movie took/brought/pulled in $1 million in its first week.

Comment: ***to pull in*** is a less common usage (and sounds more "slangy" to me). The other two are often equivalent, except ***he*** would almost always get all / most of "his takings", whereas ***she*** might only receive a tiny fraction if any of the value she "brought to the table" (in whatever relationship she might have with her "sponsors / employers").

Comment: A trader might **take** money, and that is not being rude (as if the trader *took* someone's money). "How much did you take today?" The trader then pays the **takings** into a bank.